# Tan Inverse delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm looking for a function that calculates the inverse of tan on delphi. I haven't been able to find a function in delphi that calculates the inverse of tan so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All I want to do is Tan^-1(Opposite/Adjacent)

Comment: Yes, `ArcTan` is good for that. But sometimes you need to know what quadrant the result lies. Then use `ArcTan2`.

Comment: using system.arctan keeps giving me incorrect answers. For example, arctan(0.98) gives me 0.77, where as the answer I expect is 44.6.

Comment: Never Mind, I forgot the conversion from radians

Comment: Of course, tan is not injective, so it has no inverse. However, arctan is defined to be the inverse of the restriction of tan to (-pi/2, pi/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for either: [`System.ArcTan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ArcTan) or [`Math.ArcTan2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.ArcTan2).

You might find `ArcTan2` to be more appropriate depending on your needs. The [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) might help you understand the difference between `ArcTan2` and `ArcTan`.

Comment: [Wikipedia Atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) might give a more thorough explanation between the two functions.